# How to create customized aggregation UDF function in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to create customized aggregation UDF function in Redshift?
If yes, where can I find the tutorial or documentation of that?

my data looks like

```
A     B     time_series

a1    b1    "[1,2,3]"
a1    b2    "[2,3,4]"
a2    b1    "[2,2,2]"
```

I want to groupby A or B and get the average time series.

for example, group by A

```
a1   "[1.5, 2.5, 3.5]"
a2   "[2,2,2]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today UDF can only be applied on a single row. So to achieve what you want you need to pre-combine values in  single row and then apply UDF to do the math.

For example:

Create UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_mean(time_series VARCHAR)
RETURNS varchar
IMMUTABLE AS $$
import json
data = [json.loads(x.replace('"', '')) for x in time_series.split('""')]
return json.dumps([sum(e)/float(len(e)) for e in zip(*data)])
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Use [LISTAGG](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html) function to combine values into single row. And then appy UDF.

```
mydb=> select A, f_mean(listagg(time_series)) within group (order by A) from my_table group by A;
 a  |     f_mean      
----+-----------------
 a2 | [2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
 a1 | [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
(2 rows)
```

Comment: It has a limitation then, the length of time_series could never exceed the maximal allowed length of listagg